# Pythonic efficient way to compute the mean of two successives arrays and add the resulted array between them

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

l have 9000 array of arrays called `my_data=(9000,)`. Each array is composed of a number of arrays.

```
len(my_data[0])=345 arrays# each array of 2000 values
len(my_data[700])=222 arrays s# each array of 2000 values
```

**What l would like to do ?**

Given two successive arrays, compute their mean and add the resulted mean vector between them.

**What l have tried ?**

```
new_data=[]
for i in np.arange(len(my_data)):
    for j in np.arange(len(my_data[i]):
         mean_arrays=np.mean(my_data[i][j],my_data[i][j+1],axis=0)
         new_data.append(my_data[i][j]) # add the first array
         new_data.append(mean_arrays) # add the mean of the two arrays
          new_data.append(my_data[i][j+1]) # add the second array
new_data=np.asarray(new_data)
```

Is there any efficient way to compute that efficiently in less time and in pythonic way to avoid the  nested for loops ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have an array of arrays?  It is no better than a list of arrays.  Try to get all your data into a single multidimensional array.

Comment: for instace my_data[0]=[ [0.45,0.12,...,017 ],[0,0.13,...,0.78  ],...,[0.23, 0.17,...,0.98]  ]

Comment: @JohnZwinck, l can't make them into a single multidimensional array because each my_data[i] is  a data example which is different from  my_data[j] where i !=j. So the process l defined  for computing the means of two successive arrays concern each  my_data[i] , but can't  for example compute the mean of the last array of  my_data[i] and the first array of  my_data[i+1]. Hope it's clear.

Comment: I believe `np.mean` take one array argument only: `np.mean(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=<no value>)`. What do you mean by `np.mean(my_data[i][j],my_data[i][j+1],axis=0)`?

Comment: np.mean([1,2,3],[4,5,6]) this what l mean @ZisIsNotZis

Comment: If you look at the documentation of `np.mean` above, that don't make sense since `np.mean` only take ***one*** argument. Running your code will result in `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list`